# Split AC installation: Need for a Vacuum Pump & Nitrogen cylinder

Tags: air-conditioning, installation

I bought a new Split AC (1 ton, LG made) and the company sent home a technician to install the unit. The guy arrived and took measurements and I quizzed  him a bit about his kit and strangely it doesn't seem to include either a vacuum pump nor a Nitrogen Cylinder.

From what little I know, I thought these two items are essential to commissioning the AC. Am I wrong in assuming this?

Or is there any reasonable way to connect the Indoor and Outdoor units and start things up using the refrigerant provided alone without using a vacuum pump (for evacuation) nor a N2 cylinder (for pressurized leak testing)?

He hasn't started the actual connections yet and I just wanted to be sure the guy knows what he is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let him install your unit.

Yes, you should pump the unit with dry nitrogen to check for leaks, then evacuate the system with a two stage pump.